# Better way to check repetitive if-statement conditions

Tags: c

I have a grid in which i'm adding different cell-blocks to, depending on what rotation I'm currently receiving.

`@@@ = Map border

#### = Obstacle

0-9 = Distance to goal-node
??? = Goal Path `

Robot's starting posture according to diagram below (ahead-sensors, 0 Rot)

Ahead-sensor --->, Left-sensor ^ and right-sensor v

```
@@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@
@@@                                                                                         @@@
@@@                                                                                         @@@
@@@                                                                                         @@@
@@@                                                                                         @@@
@@@                                                                                         @@@
@@@                                                                                         @@@
@@@                                         ###                                             @@@
@@@                                     ###  S  ###                                         @@@
@@@                                   4   3 ???   3   4                                     @@@
@@@                               4   3   2 ???   2   3   4                                 @@@
@@@                           4   3   2   1   G   1   2   3   4                              @@@
@@@                               4   3   2   1   2   3   4                                 @@@
@@@                                   4   3   2   3   4                                     @@@
@@@                                       4   3   4                                         @@@
@@@                                                                                         @@@
@@@                                                                                         @@@
@@@                                                                                         @@@
@@@                                                                                         @@@
@@@                                                                                         @@@
@@@                                                                                         @@@
@@@                                                                                         @@@
@@@                                                                                         @@@
@@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@ @@@
```

Now i'm currently checking how my robot is positioned so it can add obstacles correctly according to it's rotation.
i = y,
j = x

Right now i'm doing a bunch of if-statements like this (snippet):

(**currentRot is between 0-360**).

```
if(currentRot >= 0 && currentRot <= 45){ 
    printf("\n0-45");
    if (ir.sensor[5] > FULL_DANGER){ //left
          if(GetCellState(grid,newStart.i-1,newStart.j) != MAP_BORDER){ChangeCellState(grid,newStart.i-1,newStart.j,-3);printf("\n1,1");goto SUCCESS;} //add obs in map
    }
    if (ir.sensor[2] > FULL_DANGER){ //right
          if(GetCellState(grid,newStart.i+1,newStart.j) != MAP_BORDER){ChangeCellState(grid,newStart.i+1,newStart.j,-3);printf("\n1,2");goto SUCCESS;}
    }
    if (ir.sensor[0] > FULL_DANGER || ir.sensor[7] > FULL_DANGER){ //ahead
          if(GetCellState(grid,newStart.i,newStart.j+1) != MAP_BORDER){ChangeCellState(grid,newStart.i,newStart.j+1,-3);printf("\n1,3");goto SUCCESS;}
    }
}
if(currentRot >= 45 && currentRot <= 90){
     printf("\n45-90");
     if (ir.sensor[5] > FULL_DANGER){ //left
           if(GetCellState(grid,newStart.i,newStart.j-1) != MAP_BORDER){ChangeCellState(grid,newStart.i,newStart.j-1,-3);printf("\n1,1");goto SUCCESS;} //add obs in map
     }
     if (ir.sensor[2] > FULL_DANGER){ //right
           if(GetCellState(grid,newStart.i,newStart.j+1) != MAP_BORDER){ChangeCellState(grid,newStart.i,newStart.j+1,-3);printf("\n1,2");goto SUCCESS;}
     }
     if (ir.sensor[0] > FULL_DANGER || ir.sensor[7] > FULL_DANGER){ //ahead
           if(GetCellState(grid,newStart.i-1,newStart.j) != MAP_BORDER){ChangeCellState(grid,newStart.i-1,newStart.j,-3);printf("\n1,3");goto SUCCESS;}
     }
 }
```

Now onto **the question**: is there a better(smarter) way of checking these conditions and applying the same logic? Like, i thought of using a nested for-loop but exactly how that would work i'm not quite sure of. As of now, it's quite repetitive and ugly.

Comment: I would have used macros. but isn't that a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'm not familiar with that sub-stack. Stackoverflow is usually the place i go to when i have questions. I'll have a look tho. In theory, it's not a code-review question, it's a programming question regarding the logics of solving the task in another fashion.

Comment: if someone answers, good. If your question gets closed, post the same on codereview you'll get upvotes .

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yeah, i'll do that if it happens. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @Joel - this is asking about how to make code clearer/neater/whatever.   That qualifies as code review, not general programming.

Comment: @Peter - I wasn't aware of the codereview-substack until Jean-francois told me (seconds ago). I'll try to post it there instead.

Comment: `4   4   3   2   G` I'm not following, are you sure this is correct?

Comment: @Lundin No it's not correct, When i tried to copy in the console-output i had to manually write some parts of the print. It should be `4 3 2 1 G`

Comment: As for the question, use tables (arrays) and loops.

Comment: @Lundin hmm, could you link me to an example of what you mean specifically or write a small snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to avoid using so many if you can use a table of structure which keeps all the information you wanna compare.
 the structure will contain a pointer on function so if all the conditions are OK, the function located at the postition 'x' of your table of structure will be executed.

I'll put a little example so it's clearer to you:

```
typedef struct s_selector
{
  int first_value;
  int second_value;
  int which_sensor;
  int which_sensor_two;
  int danger;           //danger and map border aren't needed
  int map_border;       //danger and map border aren't needed
  void (*fcpointer) (void); //this is the key part that will execute the different actions
  int offset_i;
  int offset_j;
} g_selector;

//table of structure, to compare data, execute your funtion
g_selector selector[] = {
  {0, 45, 5, 5, FULL_DANGER, MAP_BORDER),
  selector_fct_one, -1, 0},
  {0, 45, 2, 2 FULL_DANGER, MAP_BORDER),
  selector_fct_two, 1, 0},
  {0, 45, 0, 7, FULL_DANGER, MAP_BORDER),
  selector_fct_three, 0, 1},
  {45, 90, 5, 5, FULL_DANGER, MAP_BORDER),
  selector_fct_four, 0, -1},
  {45, 90, 2, 2 FULL_DANGER, MAP_BORDER),
  selector_fct_five, 0, 1},
  {45, 90, 0, 7, FULL_DANGER, MAP_BORDER),
  selector_fct_six, -1, 0},
};

//I didnt wrotte all the functions but i think that you get the idea.
void selector_fct_one()
{
    ChangeCellState(grid,newStart.i-1,newStart.j,-3);
    printf("\n1,1");
    goto SUCCESS;
}

void selector_fct_two()
{
    ChangeCellState(grid,newStart.i+1,newStart.j,-3);
    printf("\n1,2");
    goto SUCCESS;
}

/* here you got all the conditions stacked in one if, when you advance in the
** table of structure, if all the conditions match then the fonction located
** at the location 'x' of the structure will be executed.*/

int current_rotation () 
{
  for (int j = 0; j <= 7; j++) //this loop goes trough all the sensor
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) // this loop check all the structure table
        {
      if (currentRot >= selector[i].first_value &&
          currentRot <= selector[i].second_value &&
          ir.sensor[j] > selector[i].danger &&
          (j == selector[i].which_sensorsensor ||
          j == selector[i].which_sensor_two) &&
          (GetCellState(grid,newStart.i + selector[i].offset_i,
          newStart.j + selector[i].offset_j) != selector[i].MAP_BORDER))
          {
            selector[i].fcpointer();
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd also throw in an enum defining which sensor goes to which number.  Thus you get e.g. `{0, 45, LEFT, LEFT, selector_fnc_one}` to define the first branch.

Comment: I like the approach, but i'm not sure this would solve anything. First of all, in GetCellState(grid,newStart.i,newStart.j+1) you are not checking if it is actually supposed to be +1 on j or i. On another note. I really like the idea of comparing the sensors and degrees like you did with `{0, 45, 5, 5, FULL_DANGER, MAP_BORDER),`.  Upvoted, maybe i can make something work out of the struct-approach.

Comment: oh yea i forget  about the +1 -1 etcc @joel but i think that you can also put it in the structure as a pointer of function, if i've got the time i'll edit that.

Comment: @Cjdcoy I can approve it as an answer if you change that (even tho it might not help me directly, perhaps someone else can use of this approach) :)

Comment: @Joel Done, I've added your GetCellState(grid,newStart.i,newStart.j) using the table of structure, it should work perfectly as you want :)